# Wordpress how to get the value of a custom field

Tags: wordpress

Im working on my website and i'm trying to get custom fields to work.
I have a page with 3 custom fields added (Experience1, Experience2, Experience3). Each of these fields have a value like "HTML/CSS - 2 Years".

Anyway I am trying to pull the value of these fields to display on part of my website. I tried using the code [here](http://www.wprecipes.com/wordpress-how-to-get-custom-fields-outside-the-loop) but had no luck. Below is a snippet of my code:

```
  <ul class="about-list">
    <li><?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'Experience1', true);
?></li>
    <li><?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'Experience2', true);
?></li>
    <li><?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($postid, 'Experience3', true);
?></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: did u check $postid has any value or not

Answer (score 1):

use like this

```
echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'Experience1', true);
```

Comment: I tried the code below but had no luck. 

<?php
global $wp_query;
$postid = $wp_query->post->ID;
echo get_post_meta($post->ID,'Experience1', true);
?>

Comment: @john did u get post id in $postid variable

Comment: Im sorry if im missing something obvious, but do i need to specify the page id? if so where? the page has an ID of 49.

Comment: @john:use your post id manually in get_post_meta like get_post_meta('50','Experience1', true).post id 50 should have Experience1 meta

Comment: Thank you! I got it working by manually inputting the pages id in get_post_meta. Can you tell me if it is possible to enter the pages title/slug instead of the page id?

Comment: @john:No,i guess your problem is. $postid = $wp_query->post->ID; $postid value is unexpected.like you are in about(20) page.but you displaying some post like hello(30).means $postid will give only 20 not 30.so please clarify